# How do I make a header consisting of svg graphics accessible to SEO and screen readers?

Tags: html, seo, accessibility

I have a `<h1>` tag that only has a SVG logo in it but it isn't accessible to webcrawlers and screen readers. How should I make it accessible to them?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I fixed a small typo in your question. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `title` and `desc` tags inside your `svg` tag to give webcrawlers an alternative. For screen readers, you should also add an `aria-label` attribute.

```
<svg aria-label="alternative for screen readers" role="img">
  <title>title</title>
  <desc>description</desc>
</svg>
```

Comment: I'll research this further to hunt down confirmation towards this approach. Curious, @Adam please provide your resource if possible.

Comment: FYI, I'm on the fence regarding whether this answer is current. I believe the intent of the original post dives deeper than just 'crawler accessibility' for us subsequent visitors to this question. E.g., I want the logo to be crawled for search results representation. Per https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/article#logo-guidelines, nope... .svg will no longer (if it ever did) produce the appropriate representation in SERP results.

Comment: @id.ot my answers focus more on web site accessibility (WCAG) than SEO. If you have a better approach for SEO, I can edit this answer with your suggestion or feel free to post this as a second answer. Thanks

Comment: Better that I not change the scope of the post 5 years after its been answered. I agree your solution is appropriate for the post. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Is the conclusion that one can't make SVG a H1 for SEO?